# How To Write Pending Tests In Go

Tags: unit-testing, go

Is there legitimate way to write down a test case for which I intent to write full test function later on? As like pending tests of mochajs?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mochajs, but isn't a test case without a test function just a comment a la a docstring or an [Example](https://blog.golang.org/examples)? Or is there some subtlety I don't understand

Comment: yes, it is! See the selected answer, working perfectly in same way!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The package docs](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) describe such example with `testing.(*T).Skip`:

> Tests and benchmarks may be skipped if not applicable with a call to the Skip method of *T and *B:
>
> ```
> func TestTimeConsuming(t *testing.T) {
>     if testing.Short() {
>         t.Skip("skipping test in short mode.")
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

The message you provided for `Skip` will be printed if you launch `go test` with a `-v` flag (in this example you'll also need to provide `-short` flag to see the skip message).

Comment: Totally worked like a charm! Thanks! Just to add, need to run "go test -v -test.short"